# Translating query to lambda

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, lambda

How do we write the following LINQ query into equivalent lambda?

Query

```
Dim Result = From R In Records _
             Select ID = R.id, Name = R.first_name &  " " & R.last_name
```

Lambda

```
Dim Result = Records.Select(Function(R) ???)
```

i.e. Not only that I want to select multiple fields, but also provide a name for each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way :

```
Dim Result = _
        Records.Select(Function(R) _
            New With { .ID = R.id, .Name = R.first_name &  " " & R.last_name })
```

Comment: Ahhhh... I was trying it using New { .ID = ... }. Thanks a ton.